# How to I make my ASUS UX305 turn on?

Tags: power, asus-laptop

My ASUS UX305 will no longer turn on, regardless of whether it is plugged in.  Earlier, I had problems with it turning off suddenly.

The battery is not charging.

Comment: Your power adapter is working fine?

Comment: Yes, I haven't seen any sign the adapter itself was at fault.

Comment: [This](http://www.tomsguide.com/answers/id-2334506/asus-zenbook-ux21a-power.html#14384033) should help.

Comment: @doriclazar It says, "Since that unit doesn't have an easily removable battery like a normal laptop I wouldn't worry about the battery removal. The power reset doesn't usually work anyhow, only in the rarest circumstances but I always recommend it first, just in case." 

For me, that did work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following.  This is probably caused by a manufacturer defect (and preferably, you should get it repaired properly immediately; see end).

However, if you need to work around the problem, this will reset the power/battery system and allow it to turn on:

1. Unplug it from the wall.
2. Unscrew the case (two of the screws are under the rubber feet) and open it up.
3. Unplug the battery (you will see +/- on the battery).
4. Plug the computer back into the wall.
5. Replug the battery.
6. Close it back up.

This is from https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/3bltyh/asus_ux305_will_not_turn_on_does_not_appear_to_be/cv5l9fl/ and it also worked for me.

NOTE: After this, the computer would only turn on when plugged in (though it stayed on after that), and the problem with it turning off suddenly continued to escalate, so I still had to send it for repair.  However, without this workaround I would have been stuck without a computer entirely at a very bad time.